# Get-ADUser filter by property length

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I can't seem to figure this out to save my life.

I want to grab all AD users where their `SAMAccountName` **length** is equal to 6.

I'm hoping for something like this

```
Get-ADuser -filter "samaccountname.length -eq 6" | out-file $outputFile -append
```

I'm writing a massive script to first dump all AD users, then loop through each dumped user and update some attributes.  This script will be run often, so I want to make it as efficient as possible.  One area that I thought could be improved is the dump process.

We have about 15 thousand users in AD, but I'm only interested in 4 thousand, specifically, the ones for which their `SamAccountName` is 6 characters. For this reason, I don't want to fill my ID output file with about 11 thousand unnecessary IDs.

I want to try and avoid an inline for-each if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ADuser - filter * | ? { $_.samaccountname.length -eq 6} | out-file -$outputfile -append
```

I usually do it with `Get-QADuser` (from Quest module) but I think `Get-ADUser` is same.

If $_.samaccountname isn't a string maybe you have to use:

```
$_.samaccountname.tostring().length
```

EDIT:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties samaccountname | ? {$_.samaccountname.length -eq 6}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, every time I run it I get prompted to enter a filter. Also, how is that grabbing the length of samaccountname? Won't it just be checking to see if the samaccountname is "6"?

Comment: Want this still get all the AD user objects then filter them?

Comment: @Arcass all users have to be tested to match filter in this way or in any other ways. There's no ways (for what i know) to avoid a foreach cycle , implicit or explicit.

Comment: This works.  If there is no way to filter before fetching all AD objects, only after, then I'll have to do this.  Running it takes only a minute in my environment, so I guess this'll do.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ADuser | where { $_.samaccountname.length -eq 6 } | out-file $outputFile -append
```